# Freshman need to locally adapt SIunits

Tags: siunitx, siunits

I just started to do my homework in `\LaTeX` to get ahead. (BTW, great motivation, learning two things at the same time.) Practicing the package SIunits at the moment. I live in scandinavia where we use **'mil'** as a unit for `\SI{10}{\kilo\meters}`.

Is there a way I can make my own custom unit of measure to work with SIunits? Personally I am doing fine with just the kilometers but my curriculum is a bit more traditional. There are not many exceptions from the basic metric system like this so no need for another package (I think).

I am grateful for any suggestions.

4th Edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mil}{mil}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\mil}
\end{document}
```

This should work!

Comment: Thx, Jake! I am still so new to this. So the program don't need to read the value as 10 km when I make my 'mil'? (math mode)

Comment: @Lars, right, you use it as `\unit{1}{\mil}`.

Comment: @Lars: You shouldn't use the `SIunits` package, that's not being developed any more. Use `\usepackage{siunitx} \DeclareSIUnit{\mil}{mil}`, then you can typeset your quantities using `\SI{1}{\mil}`.

Comment: @Jake: I have in my current situation. I will probably return in a couple of hours with more details, after I have sorted out some more of the obvious (to me, that is) stuff. Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Mathematica can do the conversion if you use mtex extension. I will show it next week.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: You need Mathematica to divide/multiply by 10?

Comment: Problem solved on my end! Just had to get rid of some 'noise'. Again, thanks alot and let me know if I should have used some other forum better suited for requests at my level.

Comment: Not really. This is not mathoverflow so all levels are welcome. But mil is so not SI :P If you have the answer feel free to post it and answer your question.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what did it since I changed several things before I successfully compiled the document the last time. The most mysterious problem was the "! Undefined control sequence. \DeclareSIUnit" in various forms that worked after restarting my editors, Texmaker and Kile.

Comment: @jake: 1mi = 1.6093km i thought.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: This is a norwegian/swedish mil=10000m (since 1889)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `siunitx` package. It is now the standard for typesetting units and numbers. Also keep in mind the the Scandinavian countries use the decimal comma as a decimal marker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},
            group-separator={\,},
            number-unit-product={\,},
            inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}},
            exponent-product={{\times}},
            separate-uncertainty=true
           ]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mil}{mil}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\SI{1}{\mil} = \SI{10}{\km} \\
\SI{1.23}{\mm}               \\
\num{1.23e5}                \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also just write `\SI{1}{mil}`. I prefer the `abbreviations = false` option, because

```
    \SI{30}{W/m^2 .K}
```

has a lot less typing than

```
    \SI{30}{\watt\per\square\metre\kelvin}
```

> **Note:** There is a `locale` option in `siunitx`, but none of the Scandinavian countries are listed. You can contribute to the community
>   by compiling a proper setup for you country.

Comment: `\SI{1.23}{mm}` should be `\SI{1.23}{\mm}`.

Comment: You don't need `abbreviations = false` for `\SI{30}{W/m^2 .K}` to work: the 'direct input' mode works whether the abbreviated units are loaded or not.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, I know, but as rule I do not load the large overhead of the abbreviations. It saves a little bit on memory and compile time

Comment: @DanieEls I'm surprised you feel the overhead for the abbreviations is 'large': there are perhaps 30 to 40 of them, and things like `\watt` are still defined in any case.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mil}{mil}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\mil}
\end{document}
```